Is there any method to convert TypeVar to type in python?
I want to convert TypeVar variable to type.
Sample code:
class Data:
  @classmethod
  def some_method(cls):
    pass

class SomeData(Data):
  pass

class Dealer[T:Data]:
  ...
  def some_method2(self):
    T.some_method() <--- Unresolved attribute reference 'some_method' for class 'TypeVar'

def main():
  dealer=Dealer[SomeData]()
  dealer.some_method2()

Is there any way to call "some_method"?
